# What is wrong with this C code for a simple calculator program?

Tags: c, calculator

**This is my code for a simple calculator in C.**
It compiles and runs but does not accept the char and executes the default statement only.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float num1,num2;
    char myOperator;

    printf("Enter two numbers and an operator (a,b,c,d for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division respectively) \n");
    scanf("%f%f%c", &num1, &num2, &myOperator);

    switch(myOperator) {
        case 'a': printf("%f", num1+num2);
        break;

        case 'b': printf("%f", num1-num2);
        break;

        case 'c': printf("%f", num1*num2);
        break;

        case 'd': printf("%f", num1/num2);
        break;

        default: printf("You did not follow the instructions");
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: `%f%f%c` ==> `%f %f %c`

Comment: First thing, always check the return value.  What input string are you giving it, and what gets displayed if you print num1, num2 and myOperator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does accept the `char`, it's just that it will take the whitespace after your second `float` as the `char`. This becomes evident it you try to enter output without any whitespace after the second `float`, such as `2 3c`.

You can skip all the whitespace after that second float by putting space in your format string, like this:

```
scanf("%f%f %c", &num1, &num2, &myOperator); // note the space before the "%c"
```

This way you can enter your input like `2 3 c` and it will take the `'c'` as the char, not the space between the `'3'` and `'c'`.

You can read about this behavior [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> whitespace characters: any single whitespace character in the format
>   string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from
>   the input (determined as if by calling [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) in a loop). Note that
>   there is no difference between `"\n"`, `" "`, `"\t\t"`, or other whitespace
>   in the format string.